# Find implicit solution

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to an implicit solution of this equation but Matlab doesn't return anything

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -y(t)-5e^{-t}-\sin(5t), \qquad y(0)=1$$

my try was like this:

```
syms y(x) t
eq=dsolve(diff(y,x)==-y(t) -5.*exp(-t)-sin(5.*t),y(0)==1)
```

I get that explicit solution couldn't be found

and when I try this in order to get implicit solutions, I get nothing either

```
eq=dsolve(diff(y,x)==-y(t) -5.*exp(-t)-sin(5.*t),y(0)==1,'Implicit')
```

what do I do?

Comment: Why implicit? It is a linear equation, you can get an explicit solution...

Comment: You have $y$ as a function of $x$ in some places and $t$ in other places.

Comment: you tag this question with numerical-methods, but you are using the symbolic toolbox to solve it. Do you want to solve it analytically or numerically?